# Firebase V9.22.1 uses XMLHTTP implementation instead of Fetch-Chrome extension-manifestv3

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, google-chrome-extension, service-worker

I'm developing chrome extension manifest v3 and im using roll up extension to use the firebase SDK V9 in my service worker, everything works fine but I get this error

```
service-worker.js:10917 Uncaught ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequest is not defined
    at new XhrConnection (service-worker.js:10917:25)
    at new XhrTextConnection (service-worker.js:11002:1)
    at NetworkRequest.newTextConnection [as connectionFactory_] (service-worker.js:11008:12)
    at doTheRequest (service-worker.js:9974:37)
    at service-worker.js:9696:13
```

I inspected the error in the service worker and it seems that the there is implementation of Xhr while I think Firebase V9 works on Fetch as it had supported service worker.

When I do "yarn list firebase" I get firebase version 9.22.1 so it means it is up to date.

I did some work around by replacing the XMLHTTP code in the service worker ((Obtained when I run the roll up extension )), I placed fetch and it did work fine to some extent but definitely the response is generated with error although the file is uploaded to the Firebase Storage.

What can be the possible cause for this?

```
    import path from "path";
    
    import babel from "@rollup/plugin-babel";
    import commonjs from "@rollup/plugin-commonjs";
    import replace from "@rollup/plugin-replace";
    import resolve from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
    
    import { emptyDir } from "rollup-plugin-empty-dir";
    import zip from "rollup-plugin-zip";
    import json from "@rollup/plugin-json";
    
    const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production";
    
    export default {
      input: "src/service-worker.js",
      output: {
        dir: "dist",
        format: "esm",
        chunkFileNames: path.join("chunks", "[name]-[hash].js"),
      },
      plugins: [
        json(),
        // Adds a Chrome extension reloader during watch mode
        // Replace environment variables
        replace({
          preventAssignment: true,
          "process.env.NODE_ENV": JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV),
        }),
        babel({
          // Do not transpile dependencies
          ignore: ["node_modules"],
          babelHelpers: "bundled",
        }),
        resolve({ browser: true }),
        commonjs(),
        // Empties the output dir before a new build
        emptyDir(),
        // Outputs a zip file in ./releases
        isProduction && zip({ dir: "releases" }),
      ],
    };
```